# Distribution of phase errors

Tags: antenna, error, phase

I have to implement a phase error model to see effect of phase errors on antenna patterns. However, the distribution of phase errors isn't provided to me. I am not sure whether to assume the phase errors to be gaussian distributed or uniformly distributed. Does anyone have any idea regarding the nature of phase errors in electrical/antenna related systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the normal gaussian distribution, there are very few (physical) phenomena that have uniform distribution. I mean, if some device is designed for a 90 degree phase shift, in practice it will have some variation. This variation will have a normal distribution. For example the chance of having a 90 degrees phase shift is the largest and the chance of having a 91 degrees phase shift is 0.01 %.

A uniform distribution says for example that the device has an equal change of giving 90 degrees phase shift as it has of giving 91 degrees phase shift. But ZERO chance of 91.001 degrees phase shift. Think about that, it's not physically possible.

Comment: I see.. However, the signal that I have assumed has its phase distributed in a finite interval [0,2pi]. So will gaussian assumption for phase error still hold in my case? Or do I need to assume a distribution that takes into account the fact that the phase is distributed in a finite interval [0,2pi] ?

Comment: Think about it, what is the difference between 0, 2pi, and 4 pi phase difference ? Also for pi, 3 pi and 5 pi phase difference. If I supplied you two sinewaves, one with a phase of 0 (zero) and the other of 2pi (360 degrees) would you be able to tell which is which ?

Comment: I won't be able to distinguish because both have phase which is multiple of pi ;) But how is this related to the distribution?

Comment: Exactly ! I am assuming that the phase error is smaller that +/- pi if it was not then how would you distinguish multi pi phase errors ? You cannot ! If the phase errors can be that large then a normal distribution will perhaps not suffice. No idea what you would need to use in that case. But in practice phase errors are not that large.

Comment: In ideal applications what RMS phase errors(standard deviation of phase errors) are considered? 2-6 degrees?

Comment: That is so application dependent that it is impossible to say.